# Minimal mutexes for std::queue producer/consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two threads that work the producer and consumer sides of a std::queue. The queue isn't often full, so I'd like to avoid the consumer grabbing the mutex that is guarding mutating the queue.

Is it okay to call `empty()` outside the mutex then only grab the mutex if there is something in the queue?

For example:

```
struct MyData{
   int a;
   int b;
};

class SpeedyAccess{
public:
   void AddDataFromThread1(MyData data){
      const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> queueMutexLock(queueAccess);
      workQueue.push(data);
   }

   void CheckFromThread2(){
      if(!workQueue.empty()) // Un-protected access...is this dangerous?
      {
         queueAccess.lock();
         MyData data = workQueue.front();
         workQueue.pop();
         queueAccess.unlock();

         ExpensiveComputation(data);
       }

   }

private:
   void ExpensiveComputation(MyData& data);

   std::queue<MyData> workQueue;
   std::mutex queueAccess;
}
```

Thread 2 does the check and isn't particularly time-critical, but will get called *a lot* (500/sec?).  Thread 1 is very time critical, a lot of stuff needs to run there, but isn't called as frequently (max 20/sec).

If I add a mutex guard around `empty()`, if the queue is empty when thread 2 comes, it won't hold the mutex for long, so might not be a big hit. However, since it gets called so frequently, it might occasionally happen at the same time something is trying to get put on the back....will this cause a substantial amount of waiting in thread 1?

Comment: No it's not okay to do unprotected access to a variable that may be modified by another thread at the same time. You need to protect the `empty()` call for the same reason you protect the `front()` call.

Comment: You can use a std::condition_variable to allow the producer to notify the consumer when new data is available in the Q. This way the consumer will not have to poll the Q endlessly.

Comment: The rule is: if you have an object that is shared with multiple threads, and at least one of them is a writer, then all access needs synchronization.  To not do so introduces a data race which has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the comments above, you should call `empty()` only under a lock.

But I believe there is a better way to do it.
You can use a [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) together with a [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), to achieve synchronization of access to the queue, without locking the mutex more than you must.

However - when using `std::condition_variable`, you must be aware that it suffers from **spurious wakeups**. You can read about it here: [Spurious wakeup - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).
You can see some code examples here: [Condition variable examples](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables).

The correct way to use a `std::condition_variable` is demonstrated below (with some comments).
This is just a minimal example to show the principle.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using MyData = int;

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cond_var;
std::queue<MyData> q;

void producer()
{
    MyData produced_val = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));   // simulate some pause between productions
        ++produced_val;
        std::cout << "produced: " << produced_val << std::endl;
        {
            // Access the Q under the lock:
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            q.push(produced_val);
            cond_var.notify_all();  // It's not a must to nofity under the lock but it might be more efficient (see @DavidSchwartz's comment below).
        }
    }
}

void consumer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        MyData consumed_val;
        {
            // Access the Q under the lock:
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            // NOTE: The following call will lock the mutex only when the the condition_varible will cause wakeup
            //       (due to `notify` or spurious wakeup).
            //       Then it will check if the Q is empty.
            //       If empty it will release the lock and continue to wait. 
            //       If not empty, the lock will be kept until out of scope.
            //       See the documentation for std::condition_variable.
            cond_var.wait(lck, []() { return !q.empty(); }); // will loop internally to handle spurious wakeups
            consumed_val = q.front();
            q.pop();
        }
        std::cout << "consumed: " << consumed_val << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));    // simulate some calculation
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread p(producer);
    std::thread c(consumer);
    while(true) {}
    p.join(); c.join(); // will never happen in our case but to remind us what is needed.
    return 0;
}
```

**Some notes:**

1. In your real code, none of the threads should run forever. You should have some mechanism to notify them to gracefully exit.
2. The global variables (`mtx`,`q` etc.) are better to be members of some context class, or passed to the `producer()` and `consumer()` as parameters.
3. This example assumes for simplicity that the producer's production rate is always low relatively to the consumer's rate. In your real code you can make it more general, by making the consumer extract all elements in the Q each time the `condition_variable` is signaled.
4. You can "play" with the `sleep_for` times for the producer and consumer to test varios timing cases.

Comment: You gratuitously make the `notify_all` more expensive by unlocking the mutex before calling it. If you call `notify_all` while holding the mutex, most modern implementations know that it cannot make any thread ready-to-run (because they need to acquire the mutex to make forward progress) and can make wait morphing optimizations. The way this is coded, both `notify_all` and the destructor of `lck` can make a thread ready-to-run, resulting in reduced performance.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz good point. I'll change it like you suggested.