# Best way of synchronising master and slave threads without using spinlocks c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I've got a slave thread that executes a infinite loop, which only executes the code within the loop once on instruction from the master thread.  eg

```
void slaveFunc(){
for(;;){
////  Wait here for go signal from Master thread
doStuff(); // doStuff() may return instantly or take hours.
}
return;
}
```

The master thread also runs a loop

```
void masterFunc(){
for(;;){
Instruct slaveThread to execute 1 iteration of the loop
Wait for slaveThread to complete 1 iteration of the loop
}
return;
}
```

Presently I'm using a `std::mutex`, so when the masterThread releases the mutex the slave thread executes an iteration of the loop. Likewise, when the slave thread releases the mutex, the master thread can instruct the slave thread to execute another iteration of the loop.  I've had to use a constantly polled std::atomic to ensure that when one thread releases the mutex, the other thread will lock it.

Is there a more graceful way of doing this, without resorting to a spinlock?

Comment: Since main threads waits for the worker anyway, why can't it call the function directly? Or perhaps the worker can be a coroutine?

Comment: You could use `std::condition_variable` this allows you to transmit a "wakeup message" to the background thread. If you're waiting for the completion of the task immediately anyways, there's little reason to use multithreading though.

Comment: I agree with HolyBlackCat. For synchronization between threads, have a look at std::future, std::async, std::promise and std::condition_variable. Just be aware with threading there is no 'free lunch' which means you will have find the right balance between speed/responsiveness and overhead due to synchronization. (PS. I still think this is a great article : "the free lunch is over"  from 2005 http://www.gotw.ca/publications/concurrency-ddj.htm)

Comment: You can see my answer here for an example of using std::condition_variable for synchronizing around a producer-consumer Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260569/minimal-mutexes-for-stdqueue-producer-consumer/72261477#72261477.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.   For clarification, the main thread is used for constant communication, I use  a ***std::timed_mutex*** and ***try_lock_for*** so it wakes periodically to look for messages whilst waiting for the slave thread to finish an iteration of the loop.      I'm a bit confused how condition_variables may be used to signal the slave thread to star work, and notify the master thread the slave thread has finished, will work through the examples.