# Do I need to lock the mutex before calling condition_variable::notify()?

Tags: c++, mutex

I'm reading some example code of `condition_variable`:

At cppreference, the `notify_one()` is called like this:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

```cpp
{
    std::lock_guard lk(m);
    ready = true;
    std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
}
cv.notify_one();
```

from the code above, it's clear that it's **not** necessary to use any `mutex` to call `notify_one()`.

But at cplusplus.com, the code is like this:
https://cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/

```cpp
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
ready = true;
cv.notify_all();
```

It *seems* that a `mutex` should be used before calling `notify_all()`.

I'm confused, is a `mutex` necessary for `notify_*()` function?

Comment: the mutex is locked to synchronize `ready = true` in both examples

Comment: cppreference specifically says "the lock does not need to be held for notification". You only need the lock to modify the shared variable, though you need the lock even if the shared variable is atomic.

Comment: A side note: IMHO cppreference.com is a better source than cplusplus.com.

Comment: You require the 'lock' only for the 'wait', if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not mandatory** to call `notify_one` or `notify_all` under the lock holding the mutex.

From the `std::condition_variable` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):
The 3rd thing the thread that intends to modify the shared variable has to do is:

> execute notify_one or notify_all on the std::condition_variable (**the
> lock does not need to be held** for notification)

*(emphasis is mine)*.

**However** - it might offer some **performance benefit** to call `notify_*` under the lock.

From the [comment to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260569/minimal-mutexes-for-stdqueue-producer-consumer/72261477#comment127671675_72261477) (credit goes to @DavidSchwartz):

> You gratuitously make the notify_all more expensive by unlocking the
> mutex before calling it. If you call notify_all while holding the
> mutex, most modern implementations know that it cannot make any thread
> ready-to-run (because they need to acquire the mutex to make forward
> progress) and can make wait morphing optimizations. The way this is
> coded, both notify_all and the destructor of lck can make a thread
> ready-to-run, resulting in reduced performance.

Comment: Very interesting input, thanks. I always assumed the opposite, as the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all) still states that "The notifying thread does not need to hold the lock on the same mutex as the one held by the waiting thread(s); in fact doing so is a pessimization, since the notified thread would immediately block again, waiting for the notifying thread to release the lock."
Sounds like smart modern compilers require a change in my coding :)

Comment: @Cedric I was also surprised. In the other answer I referred to above I originally called notify _not_ under the lock. Anyway feel free to upvote if the answer was useful ;-)

Comment: @Cedric at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one it mentions the pthreads approach, too